# How to use image built on onestep into another step

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to use bitbucket pipeline(migrating from Jenkins). Below is what I found from some blogpost

```
options:
  docker: true

pipelines:
  branches:
    development:
      - step:
          #python image with aws-cli installed
          image: example/awscli:3.8.3
          script:
            # aws login
            - eval $(aws ecr get-login --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} --no-include-email)
            # docker
            - export BUILD_ID=$BITBUCKET_BRANCH_$BITBUCKET_COMMIT_$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
            - docker build -t ${AWS_REGISTRY_URL}:$BUILD_ID .
            - docker build --target testimage --tag testimage:$BUILD_ID .
            - docker push ${AWS_REGISTRY_URL}:$BUILD_ID
            - docker tag ${AWS_REGISTRY_URL}:$BUILD_ID ${AWS_REGISTRY_URL}:development
```

So in above step I am creating 2 images, Now I want to use `testimage` image in next step to test and if test passes I want to push the main Image into the ECR. How to use image from one step into another?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access previously produced files, listing them as artifacts ([check more](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-artifacts-in-steps/)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker load/save functionality together with bitbucket artifacts, as described [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Can-I-keep-Docker-images-between-Pipeline-steps/qaq-p/748273)

In short, this is how to use it

```yaml
- step:
  name: Build docker image
  script:
    - docker build -t "repo/imagename" .
    - docker save -output tmp-image.docker repo/imagename
  artifacts:
    - tmp-image.docker
- step:
  name: Deploy to Test
  deployment: test
  script:
   - docker load --input ./tmp-image.docker
   - docker images
   # repo/imagename should be available now
```